# Prisma client dons't work when build next.js

Tags: next.js, graphql, prisma, vercel

I'm using Prisma with graphql and next.js the code is working on the development but when i build the project I get ERR ReferenceError: prisma is not defined
at resolve (/home/mahmoud/Desktop/e-learning/.next/server/pages/api/graphql.js:400:26

prisma.ts

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

let prisma: PrismaClient;

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient;
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}
export default prisma;
```

Comment: Can you try the suggested solution in this [link](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/9567#issuecomment-933269929)